# Can you pass a delegate function as an optional parameter?

Tags: vb.net, parameters, delegates, optional-parameters

I know that in Visual Basic, delegate function cannot *contain* optional parameters. But can a method take a delegate as an optional parameter?

What I want to do is this:

```
Delegate Sub MyDelegate(ByVal input As String)


Sub MyDelegateDefault(ByVal input As String)
    'by default do nothing'
End Sub


Sub MyDelegateCustom1(ByVal input As String)
    'do something here'
End Sub
```

In a different part of code:

```
Sub OtherFunction(ByVal str As String, Optional ByVal delegate As MyDelegate = AddressOf MyDelegateDefault)
    delegate(str)
End Sub

Sub ParentFunction()
    OtherFunction("", ) '< "" as string, nothing for optional delegate parameter'
End Sub
```

Note how the final function `OtherFunction` takes a optional delegate as second parameter.

Is this a thing? Can a delegate function be an optional parameter?

Comment: I'm a C# guy, but seems perfectly reasonable to me. Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: On second thought no, I'd bet it won't work because it's probably a reference type. You'd have to use "MyDelagate = null" and check for null and not call it if null.

Comment: You are correct! Setting it to VB's null keyword Nothing works properly. Add it as an answer and I will award it the correct one!

Comment: Also thank you for correctly my VB tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A parameter that is of a reference type can only be defaulted to null. Change the default value to null, check for the null condition, and don't call the delegate (do nothing).