# Pass method as optional parameter to another function

Tags: vb.net

I have function which should take another function as optional parameter and have some problems with it, can you help?

```
Function Index(Optional mydel As Func(List Of ProgramLog) = FromOneDayAgo()) As ActionResult
         Dim passedfunction as List(Of ProgramLog)
passedfunction = mydel 
Return View(FromOneDayAgo)
    End Function

  Function FromOneDayAgo() As List(Of ProgramLog)
        Dim programlog As New List(Of ProgramLog)
        ...
        Return programlog
    End Function


Function FromTwoDaysAgo() As List(Of ProgramLog)
        Dim programlog As New List(Of ProgramLog)
        ...
        Return programlog
    End Function
```

The problem is within this line how should i construct that?:

```
Function Index(Optional mydel As Func(List Of ProgramLog) = FromOneDayAgo()) As ActionResult
```

**UPDATE - my further tries:**

```
 Delegate Function MyDelegate() As List(Of ProgramLog)

    ' GET: /ProgramLog
    Function Index(Optional ByVal delegate1 As MyDelegate = Nothing) As ActionResult
        Dim proglog As New List(Of ProgramLog)
        If delegate1 Is Nothing Then
            proglog = FromOneDayAgo()       'default
        Else
            '??? check whats in delegat1 whether method : FromTwoDaysAgo ot FromThreeDaysAgo
            'and pass to proglog and then to view

        End If

        Return View(proglog)
    End Function
```

Comment: errh... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191718/can-you-pass-a-delegate-function-as-an-optional-parameter

Comment: i checked link and trying to do similary but still cant figure it out - check my further tries in main topi inside UPDATE.

Comment: so this is this ASP.Net MVC?, because thats where i see the use of View()